# xterm with screen and trap command

Tags: zsh, xterm

I am trying to create a xterm window and I don't want the user to close the window using 'X' button which led me to use the `trap` command.

```
xterm -e zsh -c "trap '' HUP INT TERM XFSZ; python"
```

The above will create a `zsh` and will start `python` process and the user can't close this xterm window.

I need to log the contents of the terminal. So, I have used `script` command.

```
xterm -e script mypgms.log  -c "trap '' HUP INT TERM XFSZ;python"
```

But, the window can still be closed with 'X' button.

What should I do to have `zsh` started with `python` process and logging done via `script` command in `xterm` where user can't close it?

Comment: That would be done in your window manager (not in xterm or zsh).